# How can i make the collisions in SUMO without the collider vehicle passing through the colliding vehicle

Tags: sumo, plexe, plexe-veins

I need help regarding the following,

How can i make the collisions in SUMO without the collider vehicle  (i.e., the following vehicle)  passing through the colliding vehicle (i.e, the vehicle in front)

Right now when the vehicles collide in SUMO, it give the collision warnings (when warning is set as a collision consequence) but at the same time the following vehicle passes through the vehicle in front after collision.
I would rather like to avoid that passing trough of the vehicle after collision is happened. i wish the vehicle stop after the collision in case if the vehicle in front is at full stop.

Is that possible to simulate in SUMO?

Thanks for your cooperation in advance,

Best regards,
/Mateen

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Safety.html) you can use the option `--collision-stoptime <TIME>` to let the vehicles stop.